# In R tesseract OCR failed for small size font text

Tags: r, ocr, tesseract

There are little font size text in png file that start with `Reference No.`  as attached image.
How can i retrieve them using OCR or other methon ？

Below code can't work (Just return `character(0)`)

[image]

```
library(magick)
library(tesseract)
input <- image_read("https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLOo1.png") %>% 
  image_convert(type = 'Grayscale') %>% 
  image_rotate(90) %>% 
  image_deskew() %>% 
  image_resize("2000x")

ocr(input) %>% 
  strsplit("\n") %>%
  unlist() %>% 
  grep("Reference No.", ., value = TRUE)
```

Comment: hi, it seems like the resolution/quality of print for the part you are interested is not good enough. I ran your code and it does recognize characters in the picture but just nothing from the reference number in the lower (or left before rotating) part. I recut the png to just show the wanted part and ran the ocr on this and it does not recognise the text also and looking at the picture it seems like it is just to tiny - meaning the pixels are not well alinging to form even boarders... possibly you can generate the picture with higher resolution (like 1200dpi or something) and work with this

Comment: The png file renderd form PDF ,  in the convert process , I input high DPI value , then the new png quantily is more clear . The OCR ok now. Thanks!